# Fe Color Matrix values for enchancing image

Tags: flutter, image, colormatrix

I was trying to use FeColorMatrix to make image filters. But there are these 2 results I am not able to achieve. They are not simple GrayScale, I tried setting different values of matrix along with brightness, saturation, exposure, contrast but could not achieve it. Can you help me with it.
This is the **original image**[image: Original Image]

**This is after applying first filter**
[image: First Filter]

**And this is after applying second filter**

[image: Second Filter]

And I am using [this website](https://fecolormatrix.com/) to manipulate fe color matrix values.

Okay I got a bit closer to the result shown in first filter. I set brightness to 0 and for matrix I use these values :

10,0,0,0,0

0,10,0,0,0

0,0,10,0,0

-1,-1,-1,1,0

and i got the following result:

[image: result]

Here if you see rest all is good but that share and save icons and text all are gone and in the original filter that part is perfectly clear and bright. What could be wrong in these values I tried.

And the method to achieve these filters should be such that can be used in flutter apps.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Here in the second filter all the greyish type colors became white and other dark colors like blue, green, black became something sharp black. And in first filter greyish became white and rest of the colors got enhanced. Can a filter like this be made using fe color matrix?

Comment: May be the filter is modifying rgb on the basis of value of rgb in original image and not applying same calculation on each one irrespective of its original rgb

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Not yet mate.....